# What is the measure for a Random Walk?

Tags: random-walk

Let $F$ be a distribution on $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $(X_1,X_2,...)$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables with distribution $F$. Then $S_0=0, S_1=X_1, S_2=X_1+X_2,...$ is called the random walk with step size distribution $F$.

When I then have an expression like
$$
P(S_1>0, S_2>0,...,S_n>0),
$$
which probability measure P on which $\sigma$-algebra is meant?

Does this have something to do with a finite alphabet and the product-sigma-algebra generated by cylinder sets, i.e. with product measure

$P([s_1,...,s_n]=\prod_{i=1}^n p(s_i)$?

Comment: On the probability triplet on which the random variables $X_i$ are defined, whatever its exact nature is. Said exact nature being irrelevant anyway. The finite alphabet + product-sigma-algebra construction is one option, but not the only one.

Comment: The exact nature is irrelevant?

Comment: Indeed, the exact nature of the probability triplet on which the random variables Xi are defined is mostly irrelevant.